# Sending mails asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, email, asynchronous

I have method as below to send email, when ever any error occurs in our application. [Yes. sending errors through mails is a separate discussion]

```
public void EmailErrorDetails()
{
    string strBodyMessage = string.Empty;
    strBodyMessage = GetEmailBodyMessage();

    if (strBodyMessage != String.Empty)
    {
        MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage();
        emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(Constants.MailFrom);
        emailMessage.To.Add(Constants.MailTo);
        emailMessage.Subject = Constants.EmailSubject;
        emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        emailMessage.Body = string.Format(strBodyMessage);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Host = Constants.EmailHostAddress;
        client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(Constants.EmailPort);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Constants.MailFrom, Constants.MailFromPassword);
        client.Send(emailMessage);


    }
}
```

I want to make this method run asynchronously in background, and the execution to move ahead.

**I read that [client.Send] itself uses asynchronous calling. So is there any benefit making the above method call asynchronous way, and if yes how can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that `client.Send` uses asynchronous calling

Assuming `client` is actually an [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.aspx), then `Send` **does not** use asynchronous calling. `SmtpClient` has a specific method for sending emails asynchronously and it's called [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync.aspx) - if you want to send an email in the background, use this instead of `Send`.

Comment: yes..client.`SendAsync(emailMessage);` ..is a way.. but is there more benefit. if i use asynch method call using delegate?

Comment: @James "*is there more benefit*" - of what exactly? You aren't being clear on what it is you want to know.

Comment: You just beat me to it, @James. +1 for saying what I was going to say.

Comment: I want to improve performance by making the sending mail logic asynch...so I was deciding between...`SendAsync` OR `asynch method call using delegate`..which one is better

Comment: @James I assume by "*asynch method call using delegate*" you mean sending an email *synchronously* but on a different thread? Why re-invent the wheel? `SendAsync` does exactly what you need, and in one line of code with the option of feedback - can't really make an argument for not using it.